# How to restart RemoteViewsService for widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

I have a widget with `RemoteViewsService` that display collection on it. I need to restart this service every time when I changed sizes of my widget so I called 
`val serviceIntent = Intent(context, WidgetService::class.java)` in
`onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` but `onGetViewFactory` not called again. Is there a way how to restart `RemoteViewsService`